# Weblogic CGIServlet NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: cgi, weblogic

I'm trying to configure CGI Servlet in weblogic. I have a simple war to test it. I have nothing special in web.xml, just a simple config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cgiDir</param-name>
        <param-value>/tmp/scripts</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>*.py</param-name>
        <param-value>/usr/bin/python</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/config/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and in server.xml

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

When I try to access localhost/cgitest/config/test.py
I'm getting an exception in logs of the server:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.servlet.Env 
at weblogic.servlet.CGIServlet.init(CGIServlet.java:72)
```

As I see, weblogic.servlet.Env is a part of weblogic.jar and it is present in the lib folder of the server. Maybe the server is somehow misconfigured. (WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.1.0)

I would appreciate any hints on finding the issue behind this. Thanks.

Comment: What is your classpath set to? It's definitely missing from your app classpath

Comment: The classpath was correct. It turned out to be a problem with some missing C library, the server was throwing an exception during startup. After providing the library it started working. Very strange issue. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of the completeness. When you request the CGIServlet for the first time (e.g. GET /cgi-bin/hello-world.sh), you will see an exception like this one:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/lurodrig/development/servers/wls1221/wls12210/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/libwlenv.so: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Installing that library solves the issue. E.g. in ubuntu `$sudo apt-get install libstdc++5`

```
<CGIServletSH: Exec script with args :[/bin/sh, /tmp/cgi-bin/hello-world.sh]>
```

Hope it helps,

Luis

BTW: thanks @damian for the hint about the C library